# Standard matrix definition and proof is a bit confusing

Tags: linear-algebra

I am most confused about their usage of the "n" variable

I am reading this text:

[image]

So it looks like T transforms each e column vector, into a new column vector with m rows. So the standard matrix has to have m rows because an m x n matrix represents a transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$. That I get.

This proof is confusing though and I'm failing in understanding how each v1 looks like:

This is the proof:

[image]

In the first line, is each $v_i$ a row vector or a column vector? When we transpose it, what is it supposed to look like?

Lastly, in the end, why does each column vector of a = $T(ei)$? How do we know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this says:

Suppose we have a basis for our vector space, and we want to transform that space.

Each column vector of the transformation matrix corresponds to the transformation applied to a particular basis vector.  Any vector $\mathbf v$ in your vector space can be described as a linear combination of basis vectors.  If we know how the basis vectors will transform, then this will describe how the entire space will transform.

UPDATE

You have some transformation, and you know what it does to the basis vectors.  You suspect that it can be represented as a matrix operating on a general vector.

$A\mathbf v = T(\mathbf v)$

The general vector is a combination of basis vectors.

$\mathbf v = v_1\mathbf e_1 +v_2\mathbf e_2+\cdots\\
T(\mathbf v) = T(v_1\mathbf e_1 +v_2\mathbf e_2+\cdots )$

The transformation is linear.

$T(\mathbf v) = v_1 T(\mathbf e_1) +v_2T(\mathbf e_2)+\cdots$

In standard matrix algebra

$A\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots \end{bmatrix} v_1 + \begin{bmatrix} a_{12}\\a_{22}\\\vdots \end{bmatrix} v_2 + \cdots$

The columns vectors of $A$ are $T(\mathbf e_1),T(\mathbf e_2),\cdots$

Comment: How did they get from the second to last line to the last line of the Ax = part of the proof.

Comment: Looks like the standard algebra of matrices to me.

Comment: I mean turning the column of a's into T(ei)

Comment: @Jwan622 Does this additional information help?

Comment: It does... the proof is kind of like equating corresponding terms right?

Answer (score 1):

Each $v_i$ are the coordinates of the vector $v$ in the usual basis.

Answer (score 1):

Each $v_i$ is just a number and $\mathbf{v}$ is a column matrix (i.e. a matrix with dimensions $n \times 1$).